# Nginx returns 127.0.0.1 on X-Forwarded-For, X-Real-Ip

Tags: go, nginx, web

I am having trouble getting visitors' IP addresses using headers X-Forwarded-For and X-Real-Ip in Gin framework (Go language) with nginx server.
Here is my nginx config file:

```
upstream fc {
    server 127.0.0.1:9004;
}
server {

      
        server_name somesubdomain.somedomain.com www.somesubdomain.somedomain.com;


location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9004/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
}
```

Thank you!

I tried with:
set_real_ip_from    0.0.0.0/0;
but it doesn't work...

Thank you!

Comment: My temporal solution and only for IPv4: c.GetHeader("X-Real-IP") where c is a type of *gin.Context